# I can't find the apache2 file in etc/php/8.1

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, server, apache2

I've already installed apache2 on the server, yet I don't find it in `/etc/php/8.1` why it's not there? and how to fix it?
[root@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx:/etc/php/8.1# ls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgWnR.jpg)

Comment: Did you [install the Apache module for PHP](https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/web-servers-linux/installing-php-for-apache-on-ubuntu/) to connect the two?

Comment: No, and that was the problem. thank you